# Extracting html elements in a given region?

Tags: html, url, screen-scraping, html-content-extraction, layout-extraction

Given a region defined by a rectangle and a url, is there any way to determine what elements lie within the given rectangle on the page at the given url?

EDIT: Screen resolution, Font size, etc.. can all be set to reasonable defaults.

Comment: what are you trying to retrieve ? image elements or HTML ?

Comment: Ideally, any html element that lies within the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the document from the URL.
- Render it (in a browser).
- For each element in the browser's DOM:

  - Get the rectangle[s] occupied by the element.
  - Compare the element's rectangle with the rectangle you're interested in.

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing. I used the pyqt version of webkit. Worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, but you would nee to use a full browser rendering engine. I'd recommend the QT implementation of [webkit](http://zrusin.blogspot.com/2007/01/more-on-webkit-qt.html). It is fairly simply to get going.

Some things you need to consider:

- Screen Resolution.
- Browser Font size.
- Browser Type.